# How to hide superior element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide `li` when I click in a `button` inside of it.

Isn't working.

```
 <li class="list-group-item jogador">
 <button class="btn btn-danger excluir">Excluir</button>
 </li>


<script>
$('.excluir').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: '/test/',
  method: 'post',
  success: function() {
   $('.jogador').closest().hide();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

tested using `$(this).prev().hide();` but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select the parent:

```
$('.excluir').click(function(){
 var $t = $(this);//so that we can use this after the callback
 $.ajax({
  url: '/test/',
  method: 'post',
  success: function() {
    $t.parent().hide();//select our parent
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.jogador` is the LI!

```
$('.excluir').click(function(){

 var $theButton = $(this);               // Reference the clicked button

 $.ajax({
  url: '/test/',
  method: 'post',
  success: function() {
      $theButton.closest("li").hide();  // and hide it's closest LI element
    }
 });

});
```